# SQL Server : Update a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a TableA

```
ID  MatCh01 Match02 Status
1    1001    12    
2    1001    12
3    1001    12
4    1002    44
5    1002    47
6    1003    22
7    1003    22
8    1004    55
9    1004    57
```

I want to populate column = status with "FAIL" when :
For same match01, there exist different match02. Expected TableA :

```
ID  MatCh01 Match02 Status
1    1001    12      NULL   
2    1001    12      NULL
3    1001    12      NULL
4    1002    44      FAIL
5    1002    47      FAIL
6    1003    22      NULL
7    1003    22      NULL
8    1004    55      FAIL
9    1004    57      FAIL
```

Please NOTE: FAIL all 'match01' if its corresponding 'match02' is different.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What exactly are you having difficulties with? We will not do your work for you, but will help with any specific issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this says Update all Values in TableA when the MAX and MIN of Column Match02 are not equal (meaning match01 has multiple rows with different values for match 02).

```
UPDATE A
SET Status = 'FAIL'
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
              a2.Match01
            FROM TableA A2
            GROUP BY a2.Match01
            HAVING MAX(Match02) <> MIN(Match02)) B ON
  A.Match01 = B.Match01
```

Answer (score 1):

When there's more than one distinct value of match02 for any match01, update those rows with the same match01.

```
UPDATE t1
SET Status = 'FAIL'
FROM TableA t1
WHERE t1.Match01 in
(
  SELECT t2.Match01
  FROM TableA t2
  GROUP BY t2.Match01
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Match02) > 1
)
```